# Downloading latest version from sourceforge

Tags: linux, bash, graphicsmagick, sourceforge

I am trying to download latest version of graphicsmagick from Sourceforge in my bash script

```
wget -q https://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/latest/download?source=files -O GraphicsMagick-LATEST.tar.gz
tar -xzvf GraphicsMagick-LATEST.tar.gz
```

The problem is that when I try to extract the tar.gz I get the following error

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

This means that the script is not downloading the latest tar.gz but rather another filetype?

Why is that happening and what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
wget -q -O - ftp://ftp.graphicsmagick.org/pub/GraphicsMagick/GraphicsMagick-LATEST.tar.gz | tar -xzvf -
```

Comment: ftp server is very slow at times

Comment: I suggest to use a mirror: ftp://ftp.icm.edu.pl/pub/unix/graphics/GraphicsMagick/GraphicsMagick-LATEST.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

Forget about my prevoius answer. The issue is not in the file.  When you use wget with your current link, you are pointing to a sourceforge page. You are not downloading the file, but you are downloading the HTML page.  Rename your file to `.html` and you can see all code of the sourceforge page.

```
wget -q https://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/latest/download?source=files -O file.html --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0"
```

Will download an HTML.

The link you provide has a javascript redirect to the correct link depending in your operating system (as I have described in my other answer). But wget cannot execute this javascript code, therefore is not redirected. Still the link is inside the HTML. Search for the the next string:

```
Problems with the download?  Please use this
```

And after this string, you can find the direct link to the last version:

```
http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/graphicsmagick/graphicsmagick/1.3.25/GraphicsMagick-1.3.25.tar.gz?r=&ts=1482426819&use_mirror=vorboss
```

(Note about that if you use the `--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0"`, the link is for the `tar.gz` not for the `.rpm`)

You must therefore download the HTML file each time, search for the download link inside the HTML (with the currently latest version), and use it in a new `wget` command.

Comment: As far as i know wget can follow up to 20 redirects.I tried with `curl`. `curl   -O -J -L  https://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/latest/download?source=files ` and i got  `GraphicsMagick-1.3.25-Q16-win32-dll.exe` file

Comment: when i added the useragent for mac to get tar,gz it didn't work though

Answer (score 0):

You are forcing the file to be renamed as a tar.gz extension. But the file is in a different format. In fact, when you download directly the link, the file is not a gz file, but a rpm file.

You need to download directly the file you want:

```
 wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/graphicsmagick/1.3.25/GraphicsMagick-1.3.25.tar.gz/download -O GraphicsMagick-LATEST.tar.gz
```

But here, you are predefining the version of the file you want to download.

Comment: Remember Sourceforge select the extension of the file depending on the arch of your SO, you can define files for Windows, Linux, etc. And the link selects the correct file for you.

Comment: i am on centos 7 here.How can i force  define the arch so as to force tar.gz download

Comment: I think Sourceforge uses the headers of your "browser". The configuration of this project is `src.rpm` for linux users and `tar.gz` for others. As you are in a linux based arch is selecting the first option. I do not know if with `wget` you can send a different header.

Comment: i tried chnaging the user agent but its didn't work . `--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X x.y; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0"`