# Untar/pack a tar file while downloading? (Is it streamable?)

Tags: extract, tar

I have a hard time figuring out how a TAR file works. I wish to build an application that extracts a tar file while it's  being downloaded. But I can't seem to find anything related to this subject.

Is this possible? How does a TAR file internally work? I have a small feeling that this is not going to be possible.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)

Comment: Untar/extract while downloading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41282975/3776858

Comment: Thanks... I was looking to hard and completely forgot there is something called a wiki ;) I feel stupid now.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

```
curl -s https://example.com/dir/file.tar.gz | tar zx   #silent
curl https://example.com/dir/file.tar.gz | tar zx
curl https://example.com/dir/file.tar.gz | tar zvx     #view files while unpacked
curl https://example.com/dir/file.tar.gz | pv -s$BYTES | tar zx  #view progress
```

If you don't have `curl` or `pv`, you might be able to install with `sudo apt install curl pv` or `sudo yum install curl pv`.