# Delete Files from .tar Archive while Extracting

Tags: tar, archive, xz

I am wondering whether I can incrementally delete the contents of an archive (at a minimum `.tar`, though ideally also `.tar.xz` or similar) as I am extracting them all. The ultimate goal is to remove the necessity to have twice the space required for the files available while downloading and extracting.

I have looked around a bit, and it seems tar has a `--remove-files` option, which is compatible with archiving, but this only seems to work when *creating* an archive. The `--delete` option seems to work when extracting as well, but it only seems to work with `.tar`. Would it in this case be possible to replace the `.tar.xz` with an unarchived `.tar` in-place and then proceed to obtain the list of contents somehow and iteratively extract them with `--delete`? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I recommend to unpack the data in the archive while downloading and not to save it locally first.

Comment: @Cyrus --- any idea how that can be done?

Comment: See: [Untar/pack a tar file while downloading? (Is it streamable?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48475351/3776858). Replace option `z` with `J`.